# Javascript Augmenting Function.prototype

Tags: javascript

I have been reading "javascript: the good part".

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
     this.prototype[name] = func;
     return this;
};
```

Example usage is:

```
Number.method('integer', function () {
    return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
});
document.writeln((-10 / 3).integer()); // -3
```

Two questions:

1. "By augmenting Function.prototype with a method *method*, we no longer have to type
   the name of the prototype property. That bit of ugliness can now be hidden." What does that mean? So it saves typing ".prototype.integer"? Doesn't seem to be super important.
2. We augmented `Function.prototype`, which sounds it's specific to functions. Number is a native type, should we have augmented `Object.prototype` instead?

Comment: [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) is a constructor, which means it *is* actually a function  :-)

Comment: 1) Yes. Developers are lazy.

Comment: Personally, I would prefer to write: `Number.prototype.integer = function(){};`.  I think that's more obvious what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks. I was reading the book and had exactly the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. It's a rather silly example in that regard.
2. Keep in mind that Javascript types are functions (e.g, `typeof Number == "function"`), and this will make much more sense.

Comment: Oh, OK, so `Number` here is actually a constructor function that makes a number. Therefore it is linked to Function.prototype.

Answer (score 1):

1. I am currently reading the same book and that seemed a bit weird to me too. I think the whole point of this is to give an example of how altering Function's prototype can be used.
2. You could eventually alter Object.prototype. But then, it would be higher up the prototype chain, and it would take more time to look it up. The whole point of the "method" is add method's to given constructor's prototype. Thus adding it to Function's prototype makes much more sense.